# Kafka partition contents redistribute

Tags: apache-kafka

If you have multiple partitions/consumers, and one falls far behind (e.g. stuck for a while on a poison event) allowing a queue to build up, is there an established pattern for re-distributing the queued events (while respecting ordering of serialisation key)?

The intent is to redistribute work from a partition/consumer with a queue to other potentially drained/idle partitions/consumers.

Comment: The underlying problem is the following: the work taken to process each event is very un-even (orders of magnitude variations, non-gaussian) and cannot be forecast based on the Kafka message, so although Kafka guarantees ordering (which is needed) and even distribution by count of events, when peak load has passed, statistically we end with one consumer with a queue while others sit idle. Overall aim is to complete processing all events as early as possible.

Comment: Hi Greg, I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is a simple no. If you have a poison message the best approach is to move it to another topic (a dead letter) and keep consuming. This approach is a lot simpler than redistributing the messages to another partition (if I understood your question correcly).

Kafka guarantees the ordering of events for a given partition. Moving messages to another partition would break this guarantee.

A suggestion: share the problem you are trying to solve rather than a potential solution. The world of Kafka is kafkaesque to say the least and the correct solutions are usually not straightforward.

## edit

I just read your comment/update. I have the feeling kafka might not be the right tool. And I would like to understand a bit more as there are two contradicting things you mentioned: (1)Ordering, but (2)happy to move messages to other consumers so they complete as quick as possible (which would break ordering). Usually the need to ordering is not real or it's possible to easily come up with a solution that doesn't require ordering.

It sounds to me that a normal queue will do what you want (pick your poison: SQS, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ...)

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Added clarification in case useful.

Comment: The ordering is necessary but applies to subsets of the event stream, i.e. they may come in small related sets, and out of millions of events you need these subsets of 2 to 10 events to remain in same order. So it seems if ordering is solved by Kafka, this performance heterogeneity means an overlay of something else is needed for load balancing across hardware.